# Retrieve data from API using Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Last evening, I coded a very basic counter app with Redux and would now like to do the same again by fetching data from a third-party API using `fetch`. However, I'm a little lost(because I've only just got started with redux) and would need assistance in understanding how I can go about from here and successfully make the API call using Redux. My code is as follows:

action.js

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

export const getData = () => async() => {
    await fetch('https://api.instantwebtools.net/v1/airlines', {
        method : 'GET'
    }).then(
        res => res.json()
    ).then(
        data => useDispatch({
            type : "GET_DATA",
            payload : data
        })
    );
};
```

reducer.js

```
const FetchData = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "GET_DATA":
            return {...state};
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default FetchData;
```

combineReducer.js(To send reducer to the index.js file)

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import FetchData from "./fetchData";

const reducer = combineReducers({
    get : FetchData
});

export default reducer;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import reducer from './reducers';

const store = createStore(reducer, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
reportWebVitals();
```

screen.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const Screen = () => {
    const selector = useSelector(state => state.get);

    return (
        <div>
            {selector.map((key, value) => <ul>
                <li>{selector[value].name}</li>
            </ul>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Screen;
```

The idea in the above component is to display only the `name` property retrieved from the json response in an unordered list. However, given my amateur-like experience in Redux, I would like to know how I can implement the same. The error I get suggests the following :

```
Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
```

The `map` doesn't seem to work for some reason but maybe that's probably because the API call isn't successful at all. I have no way of figuring out what the first error means.

The link for the API is: `https://api.instantwebtools.net/v1/airlines`
Also, I have shared a small snippet of what the response actually looks like

```
[
  {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Quatar Airways",
  "country": "Quatar",
  "logo": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/9b/Qatar_Airways_Logo.svg/300px-Qatar_Airways_Logo.svg.png",
  "slogan": "Going Places Together",
  "head_quaters": "Qatar Airways Towers, Doha, Qatar",
  "website": "www.qatarairways.com",
  "established": "1994"
  },
  {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Singapore Airlines",
  "country": "Singapore",
  "logo": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/6/6b/Singapore_Airlines_Logo_2.svg/250px-Singapore_Airlines_Logo_2.svg.png",
  "slogan": "A Great Way to Fly",
  "head_quaters": "Airline House, 25 Airline Road, Singapore 819829",
  "website": "www.singaporeair.com",
  "established": "1947"
  },
]
```

Comment: your usage of dispatch is incorrect. `useDispatch` is a hook that needs to be in a react component. Here you'd need to reference the `store.dispatch`

Comment: `const dispatch = useDispatch(); // ... dispatch({ type : "GET_DATA", payload: data })`

Comment: You are writing a quite outdated style of Redux here - modern Redux does not use switch..case reducers, ACTION_TYPES or createStore. I'd recommend you follow the official Redux tutorial which will also show you in chapter 5 how to do api requests by hand and in chapter 8 how to automate most of the code. https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts